# Calling constructor of parent class gives undefined

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

```
Class A{
  public:  
  int variable;
  A(): variable(4) {}
};

class B : public A{

  void  function(){

    A test = new A()
  }
};
```

Calling new A in class B gives undefined reference to A:A().
Is this call legal?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5f022f69113351cd0a0e4a36710d348c-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f) Post real code.

Comment: This is not your real code. Show the real code (where you probably forgot to define `A`'s constructor)

Comment: Your code won't even compile. How about a clear working example?

Comment: the constructor of A is   A(): variable(4) {}

Comment: Here's what the updated code gives. Nothing like what you described: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7ddcb4799761a66c3b5dd64f01a5f222-8a676986784bd3a58ce3ec015645a41f

Answer (score 1):

No -- you've defined only one constructor for `A`, and it's private. Therefore, nothing can construct an `A` unless it's a friend of `A`, or you also define (for example) a static member of `A` to create an instance.

Also note that `new A` (by itself) does nothing useful (actually, as it stands right now, with no semicolon, it won't even compile). `new` yields the address of an object -- to make any real use of it, you typically save that address into a pointer.